# How can you link against (non-standard) libraries from Terra?

Tags: lua

I'd like to use [raylib](http://www.raylib.com/) with [Terra](http://terralang.org/)/Lua (better metaprogramming) but the official examples only show how to interface with the C standard library, which I assume Terra is linked against already.

But raylib has a header (`raylib.h`, I know how to include it in terra) and a `so`/`dll` file (the actual code of the library).

How can I link my Terra cide against raylib?

P.S. I'm interested in writing mostly Terra and just doing macros in Lua which is the third use case listed on the Terra website:

> A stand-alone low-level language. Terra was designed so that it can
>   run independently from Lua. In fact, if your final program doesn’t
>   need Lua, you can save Terra code into a .o file or executable. In
>   addition to ensuring a clean separation between high- and low-level
>   code, this design lets you use Terra as a stand-alone low-level
>   language. In this use-case, Lua serves as a powerful meta-programming
>   language. Here it serves as a replacement for C++ template
>   metaprogramming or C preprocessor X-Macros with better syntax and
>   nicer properties such as hygiene. Since Terra exists only as code
>   embedded in a Lua meta-program, features that are normally built into
>   low-level languages can be implemented as Lua libraries. This design
>   keeps the core of Terra simple, while enabling powerful behavior such
>   as conditional compilation, namespaces, templating, and even class
>   systems implemented as libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I found what I need.

> `terralib.linklibrary(filename)`
>
> Load the dynamic library in file
> filename. If header files imported with includec contain declarations
> whose definitions are not linked into the executable in which Terra is
> run, then it is necessary to dynamically load the definitions with
> linklibrary. This situation arises when using external libraries with
> the terra REPL/driver application.

Source: [Terra docs](http://terralang.org/api.html#c-backwards-compatibility)